# Cannot open file after downloading from Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc

After downloaded a file from Server (pdf, jpg,..) successfully, I couldn't open that file in my computer. 
It said "It looks like we don't support this file format". Files are stored and readable on Server.
Wonder if there is something missing in my Download Function:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Download(Guid? attachmentId)
{
    var visitAttachment = _visitAttachmentService.FindOne(x => x.Id == attachmentId);
    try
    {
        var serverPath = Server.MapPath(visitAttachment.Path);
        byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(serverPath);
        return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, visitAttachment.AttachmentName);
    }
    catch
    {
        return File(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(""), System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, visitAttachment.AttachmentName);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure `visitAttachment.AttachmentName` have the  file extension?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like file not downloaded properly, try this, may it help, good luck

```
  FileDownload(yourfilepath ,yourfilenamewithFormat)
    {
        string filename = yourfilenamewithFormat;
        byte[] file_Bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(yourfilepath);
        return File(file_Bytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, filename);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My opinion, is that you can be missing the file extension. If that is the case you can get it by the using  `Path.GetExtension(serverPath)`

**Edited**

Try to use `FileResult` instead of `ActionResult`

```
[HttpGet]
public FileResult Download(Guid? attachmentId)
{
    var visitAttachment = _visitAttachmentService.FindOne(x => x.Id == attachmentId);
    try
    {
        var serverPath = Server.MapPath(visitAttachment.Path);
        byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(serverPath);
        return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, visitAttachment.AttachmentName);

    }
    catch
    {
        return File(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(""), System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, visitAttachment.AttachmentName);
    }

}
```

Comment: @vyclarks that's weird... Try to use `FileResult` instead of `ActionResult`

Comment: @vyclarks any progress?